# CPU bound web apps with servlet 3.1 performance

Tags: java, spring, servlets, spring-boot, vert.x

We are developing a spring boot 1.5.x webapp with some complex calculations (basic arithmetic stuff, but lots of it). The app has no I/O. Each request takes about 100-200ms.

We are expecting relatively high load for that app. I was wondering if using servlet 3.1 (something like reactive spring, vert.x etc.) might improve throughput.

Nearly all of the resources I've checked says that servlet 3.1 is good for improving throughput for I/O bound apps but I couldn't find any benchmarks for CPU bound apps.

Comment: It will improve throughput it will NOT improve your performance. The request handling threads hand off the work to another thread which means it can handle another request like serving a page. Instead of what normally happens is to block and wait for the request to finish. So yes it might improve throughput it will NOT improve your performance. Using Servlet 3.1 has nothing to do with building a reactive application that is a completely different architecture which again will not improve your performance (generally) but improves scalability.

Comment: Thank you for clarification, I will accept if you send it as answer. I might have messed up with terminology, what I actually meant by Servlet 3.1 is "Servlet 3.1 non-blocking I/O" as decribed in this post https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.0.0.M1/spring-framework-reference/html/web-reactive.html.

Answer (score 0):

You're already using Servlet 3.1 if you're using Spring Boot (Servlet 3.1 spec came out in 2013). Since you don't even know what you're using currently, I'd suggest you don't try to *guess* things to do.

Do load testing and profile your application and see what the performance bottlenecks are. Only then you can start deciding on what can and needs to be done.